# App crashes on home button with service open

Tags: android

I've been trying to resolve this problem for a few days now but I'm having no luck. Here's the issue.

So I have a service window that opens the in-app billing window, works fine in every scenario except one: When the user closes the screen by pressing the HOME button on the phone then re-opens the app. The window is still open but the app crashes in the background. So, the app crashes then the window is still open, user can still react with it.

When the user presses the app account it's just a black screen, nothing else.

I have a service specifically:

This is created in the Activities "onCreate".

```
    ServiceConnectionToBilling mServiceConnection = new ServiceConnectionToBilling();
    bindService(new Intent("com.android.vending.billing.InAppBillingService.BIND"), mServiceConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
    mInAppPurchasingEngine = new InAppPurchasingEngine(this, this, mServiceConnection);
```

So my question is, how do I deal with this? I'v been trying to call the Back Button before the user presses the HOME button (as this closes the service window) but of course overriding the HOME button is just fail on Android so I've no idea how to handle this.

PS I have this:

```
public void onDestroy()
{ 
    if(mServiceConnection != null)
    {
        unbindService(mServiceConnection);
    }

    mGameScreen.DestoryEngine();

    super.onDestroy();
    finish();
}
```

StackTrace:

```
http://pastebin.com/gakrL7qV
```

I know this error, but how on earth do I deal with it? Only happens when closing the app using home button.

Comment: post the stack trace from Logcat

Comment: Post the full stack trace.  What you posted isn't the trace, its a warning printed by the system after the crash.

Comment: I've posted it. There is no way to fix this.

Comment: haha of course there's way to fix it...

Answer (score 0):

The reason why is happening is because you are not unbinding the service in scenarios where onDestroy is not being called like "Pressing Home", notice that pressing home only calls "onPause" and "onStop", hence, in order to fix this issue you need to do what you are doing in onDestroy (unbind service) during "onPause" and bind again "onResume", so when user press home the unbinding method is properly called, and when the activity is reopened the "onResume" will try to bind the service again...

Regards!

Comment: Problem is the service calls "onPaused" when it's opened :-/.

Comment: only if you are sending something over your activity, otherway the workflow must be, "onCreate", "onStart", "onResume"

Comment: The user clicks a button, the Service window opens and calls onPause(). The user closes the app using home, onPause(), onStop() is called. The user opens the app again, onStart(), onResume() is called. The app crashes no matter where unbind and bind is.

Comment: really weird, in the log you posted seems like is always crashing in "onCreate", so if you are pressing home, its not supposed to call onCreate unless you are doing something to start the activity again...

Comment: It's calling onCreate() when I resume the activity while the intent is open (service to in-app billing window). Works fine otherwise.